# Duel win probability given two means and two standard deviatons

Tags: probability

I'm working on a personal project where I calculated the average seconds to kill and standard deviation of seconds to kill for each of two tanks. How do I calculate the probability that tank1 survives longer than tank2, i.e. tank1 kills tank2.
Example values:

tank1: mean=32 seconds, sd=23 seconds

tank2: mean=34 seconds, sd=5 seconds

Edit:
I calculated the deflection chance, mean, standard deviation, etc with excel vba custom functions. After more research, I'm guessing I need to use a hypothesis test for a difference in two population means.

In terms of the game, the two different tanks have different deflection chance, health pool, different ammunition, and different reload speeds, among other things. I synthesized all this down into mean time to kill and the standard deviation of time to kill (which occurs due to deflection chance). I just needed to figure out how to compare them given that I've already calculated the mean & sd. I was guessing some kind of probability because it's possible given the standard deviation that in some unlikely circumstance the tank with the lower time to kill (i.e. less durable) could outlast the other tank due to deflecting many shells. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8yFY.jpg

Comment: I don't understand the "rules of the game" and I must not be alone. Could you explain a little more, maybe by showing a simulation program ?

Comment: If you're assuming that the distributions are independent and normal, then you can use the fact that $X-Y \sim \mathscr{N}\left(\mu_x-\mu_y, \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}\right)$, and use $P[X>Y]=P[X-Y>0]$.